# i am getting following error "Error in if (num < 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed" in R program

Tags: r

When executing the following factorial program in R, i am getting the following error "Error in if (num < 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

```
fact_num = as.integer(readline("Enter the factorial number:"))
factorial = 1
if(fact_num < 0){
  print("Input cannot be negative")
}else if(fact_num==0){
  print("The factorial of 0 is 1")
}else{
  for (i in 1:fact_num) {
    factorial= factorial*i
  }
  print(paste("The factorial of", fact_num, " is", factorial))
}
```

Comment: Your error message doesn't match the code that you show.  The code uses `fact_num`, but the error message that you quote says `if (num < 0)`.

Comment: Your code works fine.

Comment: Are you executing all your code at once? You have to first execute your first line where you enter the factorial number into the console, then you can run the remaining lines. Running the code all at once gives me an error.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your code correctly, it looks like the way you would get that error is by not inputing a value when it prompts you with the first line.  This will result in an *NA_integer_* value being assigned to **fact_num** which will then cause it to error out when it tries to evaluate **fact_num < 0**

You could add an if statement to the front of your code to check for a missing value to avoid that error like so:

```
fact_num = as.integer(readline("Enter the factorial number:"))
factorial = 1
if(is.na(fact_num)) {
  print("Plese input a value")
}else if(fact_num < 0){
  print("Input cannot be negative")
} ... etc
```